# How do I bring the "HEADING" to the header of the document?

Tags: header-footer, titles

I have a TeX script (that I modified from somewhere) that makes the heading look like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathabx}  
\usepackage{accents}  
\usepackage{xcolor}   
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{calc}     
\usepackage{bm}       
\newcommand*{\uarr}[1]{\underaccent{\resizebox{\widthof{#1}}{\height}{$\color{black}\bm{\curvearrowbotleft}$}}{#1}}

\newlength{\toppush}
\setlength{\toppush}{2\headheight}
\addtolength{\toppush}{\headsep}

\newcommand{\htitle}[3]{\noindent\vspace*{-\toppush}\newline\parbox{6.5in}
{\bf{}\hfill\newline
\bf{Author} \hfill #3\newline
%\hfill Handout #1\vspace*{-.5ex}\newline
\mbox{}\hrulefill\mbox{}}\vspace*{1ex}\mbox{}\newline
\begin{center}{\Large\bf #2}\end{center}}

\newcommand{\handout}[3]{\thispagestyle{empty}
 %\markboth{Handout #1: #2}{Handout #1: #2}
 \pagestyle{myheadings}\htitle{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}
\begin{document}

\handout{3}{\bf{\underline{HEADING}}}{\today}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    
\newcommand{\remark}{{\textit{Remark }}}
    
Document starts here.

\end{document}
```

With this, the document looks like this:

[image: Original].

The "HEADING" is not properly at the center and it is below the line. I would like to have it above the line.

Somewhat like this (I used a photo editor for this):

[image]

Comment: Do you mind to use `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`? It has some predefined rules to perform exactly the those type of things. You may check it for further information from [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

Comment: @OnurGürdoğan I can use that as long as my font and spacing remains same. I have no idea about using LaTeX; I copied this template from somewhere and I would like to have a similar format.

Comment: Then you should select your path on your own.. I thought your MWE was yours, but apparently not.. Please do more investigations about the packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use `\usepackage{fancyheader}` as given below:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{Header}
\fancyhead[L]{Test}
\fancyhead[R]{\today}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{Test}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}

\begin{document}
Bla bla bla..
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Please provide your own MWE next time..